# MYSQL Select latest entry from table and reference latest entry of the other table

Tags: mysql

I have these tables:

action table:

```
       +------+-------+--------------------------------------+
       | id   | action   | contact_list_id                   |
       +------+-------+--------------------------------------+0
       | 1    | 1        | 1234                              |
       | 2    | 1        | 1235                              |
       | 3    | 2        | 1234                              |
       | 4    | 3        | 1235                              |
       +------+-------+--------------------------------------+
```

contact list table:

```
       +------+-------+--------------------------------------+
       | id   | user_id | updated_by                         |
       +------+-------+--------------------------------------+0
       | 1234 | 1        | 1                                 |
       | 1235 | 1        | 1                                 |
       | 1236 | 2        | 1                                 |
       +------+-------+--------------------------------------+
```

I have to find the latest action table entry that returns only one row
having user_id = 1

I tried this but its not returning the proper result:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM contact_list a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(id)
    FROM action
    GROUP BY id
) b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE user_id = 1
```

Expected result:

```
       +------+-------+--------------------------------------+
       | id   | action   | contact_list_id                   |
       +------+-------+--------------------------------------+0
                                 |
       | 4    | 3        | 1235                              |
       +------+-------+--------------------------------------+
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Please provide the desired result

Comment: You should join the table `action` on `contact_list_id` and not on `id`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess by *latest* you mean *having the largest `id` value*. Keep in mind that there's no inherent order to rows in tables. You always have to say what you mean by words like latest and earliest.

Let's work this out bit by bit.

First, a subquery to get the largest action.id for each contact list id.

```
                  SELECT MAX(id) id, contact_list_id
                    FROM action 
                   GROUP BY contact_list_id
```

Next, use that subquery to pull out the rows you want from your action table

```
       SELECT action.id, action.action, action.contact_list_id
         FROM action
         JOIN (
                  SELECT MAX(id) id, contact_list_id
                    FROM action 
                   GROUP BY contact_list_id
              )maxaction ON action.contact_list_id = maxaction.contact_list_id
```

Next, join that to your contact table and add a WHERE clause to get the row you need.

```
       SELECT action.id, action.action, action.contact_list_id
         FROM action
         JOIN (
                  SELECT MAX(id) id, contact_list_id
                    FROM action 
                   GROUP BY contact_list_id
              ) maxaction ON action.contact_list_id = maxaction.contact_list_id
         JOIN contact ON action.contact_list_id = contact.contact_list_id
        WHERE contact.user_id = 1
```

Summary:

1. find the `id` values of the "latest" rows.
2. find the details from the latest rows with a JOIN.
3. JOIN the other table to get the user_id values.
4. Filter the user_id you want with a WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use next solution fro your problem:

```
SELECT * 
FROM action 
WHERE id = (
    -- here sub-query for get last action id for user 1
    SELECT MAX(action.id)
    FROM `action`
    JOIN contact_list ON contact_list.id = action.contact_list_id
    WHERE user_id = 1
);
```

You can test the query on [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=58582ffad3751556993fd1e7ac3f104f&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)